# Strange LINQ joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've got a very strange behaviour in LINQ joins

I'm joining a IEnumerable collection and a view which i'm accessing through Entity Framework.

For example (numbers are column values):

Collection

```
1 1

1 2
```

View

```
1 3

1 4
```

Result of a join should be

```
1 1 1 3

1 1 1 4

1 2 1 3

1 2 1 4
```

And i get that result in T-SQL in managment studio and even using the same code in LinqPad,
but in VS i get

```
1 1 1 3

1 1 1 3

1 2 1 3

1 2 1 3
```

or

```
1 1 1 4

1 1 1 4

1 2 1 4

1 2 1 4
```

but never the correct join. I check Linq generated query through SQL Server Profiler and launched it in Managment Stuiod, and got the correct answer. Please help me to understand such very strange behaviour

```
            var allocations = InvoicingContext.vAllocations.Where(x => auditIds.Contains(x.AuditGroupId.Value)).AsEnumerable();

        var q = from a in allocations
                join c in CommonCodesContext.vContainerEntity on a.ContainerId equals c.ContainerId                   
                select new ContainerServiceModel
                {
                    ContainerNo =  a.ContainerNo,
                    PortATD = c.ATD,
                    ATA_KL = a.ServiceDate,
                    RateWithoutVat = a.RateWithoutVat,                        
                    DestinationCityId = c.DestinationCityId,
                    Quantity = 1
                };

        var containerServiceModels = q.ToList();

        int destinationCount = containerServiceModels.Where(x => x.DestinationCityId == 14).Count();
```

Queries generated for Linq code (Visual Studio)

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ShipperID] AS [ShipperID], 
[Extent1].[CarrierId] AS [CarrierId], 
[Extent1].[ShippingLineID] AS [ShippingLineID], 
[Extent1].[TerminalId] AS [TerminalId], 
[Extent1].[Terminal] AS [Terminal], 
[Extent1].[ContainerId] AS [ContainerId], 
[Extent1].[ContainerNo] AS [ContainerNo], 
[Extent1].[ContTypeID] AS [ContTypeID], 
[Extent1].[PortStorageDays] AS [PortStorageDays], 
[Extent1].[UnloadDate] AS [UnloadDate], 
[Extent1].[ATA] AS [ATA], 
[Extent1].[ATD] AS [ATD], 
[Extent1].[PortShipped] AS [PortShipped], 
[Extent1].[IsSealed] AS [IsSealed], 
[Extent1].[ATA_CY] AS [ATA_CY], 
[Extent1].[ATD_CY] AS [ATD_CY], 
[Extent1].[InspectionDate] AS [InspectionDate], 
[Extent1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
[Extent1].[OrderTypeId] AS [OrderTypeId], 
[Extent1].[StorageTypeId] AS [StorageTypeId], 
[Extent1].[LoadRegionId] AS [LoadRegionId], 
[Extent1].[LoadCityId] AS [LoadCityId], 
[Extent1].[DestinationRegionId] AS [DestinationRegionId], 
[Extent1].[DestinationCityId] AS [DestinationCityId], 
[Extent1].[ODCYCustomer] AS [ODCYCustomer], 
[Extent1].[ODCYShipped] AS [ODCYShipped], 
[Extent1].[PortReturnDate] AS [PortReturnDate], 
[Extent1].[IsReturnedToPort] AS [IsReturnedToPort], 
[Extent1].[ODCYStorageDays] AS [ODCYStorageDays], 
[Extent1].[DetentionDays] AS [DetentionDays], 
[Extent1].[CCFinish] AS [CCFinish], 
[Extent1].[FreeDaysForTrucker] AS [FreeDaysForTrucker], 
[Extent1].[TruckingUnloadDays] AS [TruckingUnloadDays], 
[Extent1].[TruckingEmptyReturnDays] AS [TruckingEmptyReturnDays], 
[Extent1].[TruckingEmptyReturnDetentionDays] AS [TruckingEmptyReturnDetentionDays], 
[Extent1].[LatePickUpDays] AS [LatePickUpDays]
FROM (SELECT 
  [vContainerEntity].[ShipperID] AS [ShipperID], 
  [vContainerEntity].[CarrierId] AS [CarrierId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ShippingLineID] AS [ShippingLineID], 
  [vContainerEntity].[TerminalId] AS [TerminalId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[Terminal] AS [Terminal], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ContainerId] AS [ContainerId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ContainerNo] AS [ContainerNo], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ContTypeID] AS [ContTypeID], 
  [vContainerEntity].[PortStorageDays] AS [PortStorageDays], 
  [vContainerEntity].[UnloadDate] AS [UnloadDate], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ATA] AS [ATA], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ATD] AS [ATD], 
  [vContainerEntity].[PortShipped] AS [PortShipped], 
  [vContainerEntity].[IsSealed] AS [IsSealed], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ATA_CY] AS [ATA_CY], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ATD_CY] AS [ATD_CY], 
  [vContainerEntity].[InspectionDate] AS [InspectionDate], 
  [vContainerEntity].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[OrderTypeId] AS [OrderTypeId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[StorageTypeId] AS [StorageTypeId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[LoadRegionId] AS [LoadRegionId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[LoadCityId] AS [LoadCityId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[DestinationRegionId] AS [DestinationRegionId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[DestinationCityId] AS [DestinationCityId], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ODCYCustomer] AS [ODCYCustomer], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ODCYShipped] AS [ODCYShipped], 
  [vContainerEntity].[PortReturnDate] AS [PortReturnDate], 
  [vContainerEntity].[IsReturnedToPort] AS [IsReturnedToPort], 
  [vContainerEntity].[ODCYStorageDays] AS [ODCYStorageDays], 
  [vContainerEntity].[DetentionDays] AS [DetentionDays], 
  [vContainerEntity].[CCFinish] AS [CCFinish], 
  [vContainerEntity].[FreeDaysForTrucker] AS [FreeDaysForTrucker], 
  [vContainerEntity].[TruckingUnloadDays] AS [TruckingUnloadDays], 
  [vContainerEntity].[TruckingEmptyReturnDays] AS [TruckingEmptyReturnDays], 
  [vContainerEntity].[TruckingEmptyReturnDetentionDays] AS [TruckingEmptyReturnDetentionDays], 
  [vContainerEntity].[LatePickUpDays] AS [LatePickUpDays]
  FROM [Tariff].[vContainerEntity] AS [vContainerEntity]) AS [Extent1]
```

and

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[Payer] AS [Payer], 
[Extent1].[Receiver] AS [Receiver], 
[Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
[Extent1].[CustomerName] AS [CustomerName], 
[Extent1].[AuditGroupId] AS [AuditGroupId], 
[Extent1].[ContainerId] AS [ContainerId], 
[Extent1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
[Extent1].[ContainerNo] AS [ContainerNo], 
[Extent1].[TariffId] AS [TariffId], 
[Extent1].[ServiceTypeId] AS [ServiceTypeId], 
[Extent1].[ServiceType] AS [ServiceType], 
[Extent1].[ServiceDate] AS [ServiceDate], 
[Extent1].[IsServiceDateClosed] AS [IsServiceDateClosed], 
[Extent1].[InvoiceId] AS [InvoiceId], 
[Extent1].[InvoiceNo] AS [InvoiceNo], 
[Extent1].[InvoiceDate] AS [InvoiceDate], 
[Extent1].[ReceiveDate] AS [ReceiveDate], 
[Extent1].[DueDate] AS [DueDate], 
[Extent1].[ResponsibleUser] AS [ResponsibleUser], 
[Extent1].[Free] AS [Free], 
[Extent1].[PaymentQty] AS [PaymentQty], 
[Extent1].[RateWithoutVat] AS [RateWithoutVat], 
[Extent1].[RateWithVat] AS [RateWithVat], 
[Extent1].[AmountWithoutVat] AS [AmountWithoutVat], 
[Extent1].[CommissionWithoutVat] AS [CommissionWithoutVat], 
[Extent1].[TotalAmountWithoutVat] AS [TotalAmountWithoutVat], 
[Extent1].[AmountWithVat] AS [AmountWithVat], 
[Extent1].[CommissionWithVat] AS [CommissionWithVat], 
[Extent1].[TotalAmountWithVat] AS [TotalAmountWithVat], 
[Extent1].[VatSum] AS [VatSum], 
[Extent1].[RateWithoutVatRub] AS [RateWithoutVatRub], 
[Extent1].[RateWithVatRub] AS [RateWithVatRub], 
[Extent1].[AmountWithoutVatRub] AS [AmountWithoutVatRub], 
[Extent1].[CommissionAmountWithoutVatInRub] AS [CommissionAmountWithoutVatInRub], 
[Extent1].[TotalAmountWithoutVatRub] AS [TotalAmountWithoutVatRub], 
[Extent1].[AmountWithVatRub] AS [AmountWithVatRub], 
[Extent1].[CommissionAmountWithVatInRub] AS [CommissionAmountWithVatInRub], 
[Extent1].[TotalAmountWithVatRub] AS [TotalAmountWithVatRub], 
[Extent1].[AmountVatRub] AS [AmountVatRub], 
[Extent1].[CommissionVatRub] AS [CommissionVatRub], 
[Extent1].[VatSumInRub] AS [VatSumInRub], 
[Extent1].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
[Extent1].[IncludeVat] AS [IncludeVat], 
[Extent1].[VAT] AS [VAT], 
[Extent1].[IncludeVatInCommission] AS [IncludeVatInCommission], 
[Extent1].[ExchangeDate] AS [ExchangeDate], 
[Extent1].[ExchangeDateForCommission] AS [ExchangeDateForCommission], 
[Extent1].[ExchangeRate] AS [ExchangeRate], 
[Extent1].[CommissionExchangeRate] AS [CommissionExchangeRate], 
[Extent1].[AverageExchangeRate] AS [AverageExchangeRate], 
[Extent1].[StatusId] AS [StatusId], 
[Extent1].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
[Extent1].[Author] AS [Author], 
[Extent1].[DtCreated] AS [DtCreated]
FROM (SELECT 
  [vAllocations].[id] AS [id], 
  [vAllocations].[Payer] AS [Payer], 
  [vAllocations].[Receiver] AS [Receiver], 
  [vAllocations].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId], 
  [vAllocations].[CustomerName] AS [CustomerName], 
  [vAllocations].[AuditGroupId] AS [AuditGroupId], 
  [vAllocations].[ContainerId] AS [ContainerId], 
  [vAllocations].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
  [vAllocations].[ContainerNo] AS [ContainerNo], 
  [vAllocations].[TariffId] AS [TariffId], 
  [vAllocations].[ServiceTypeId] AS [ServiceTypeId], 
  [vAllocations].[ServiceType] AS [ServiceType], 
  [vAllocations].[ServiceDate] AS [ServiceDate], 
  [vAllocations].[IsServiceDateClosed] AS [IsServiceDateClosed], 
  [vAllocations].[InvoiceId] AS [InvoiceId], 
  [vAllocations].[InvoiceNo] AS [InvoiceNo], 
  [vAllocations].[InvoiceDate] AS [InvoiceDate], 
  [vAllocations].[ReceiveDate] AS [ReceiveDate], 
  [vAllocations].[DueDate] AS [DueDate], 
  [vAllocations].[ResponsibleUser] AS [ResponsibleUser], 
  [vAllocations].[Free] AS [Free], 
  [vAllocations].[PaymentQty] AS [PaymentQty], 
  [vAllocations].[RateWithoutVat] AS [RateWithoutVat], 
  [vAllocations].[RateWithVat] AS [RateWithVat], 
  [vAllocations].[AmountWithoutVat] AS [AmountWithoutVat], 
  [vAllocations].[CommissionWithoutVat] AS [CommissionWithoutVat], 
  [vAllocations].[TotalAmountWithoutVat] AS [TotalAmountWithoutVat], 
  [vAllocations].[AmountWithVat] AS [AmountWithVat], 
  [vAllocations].[CommissionWithVat] AS [CommissionWithVat], 
  [vAllocations].[TotalAmountWithVat] AS [TotalAmountWithVat], 
  [vAllocations].[VatSum] AS [VatSum], 
  [vAllocations].[RateWithoutVatRub] AS [RateWithoutVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[RateWithVatRub] AS [RateWithVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[AmountWithoutVatRub] AS [AmountWithoutVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[CommissionAmountWithoutVatInRub] AS [CommissionAmountWithoutVatInRub], 
  [vAllocations].[TotalAmountWithoutVatRub] AS [TotalAmountWithoutVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[AmountWithVatRub] AS [AmountWithVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[CommissionAmountWithVatInRub] AS [CommissionAmountWithVatInRub], 
  [vAllocations].[TotalAmountWithVatRub] AS [TotalAmountWithVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[AmountVatRub] AS [AmountVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[CommissionVatRub] AS [CommissionVatRub], 
  [vAllocations].[VatSumInRub] AS [VatSumInRub], 
  [vAllocations].[CurrencyId] AS [CurrencyId], 
  [vAllocations].[IncludeVat] AS [IncludeVat], 
  [vAllocations].[VAT] AS [VAT], 
  [vAllocations].[IncludeVatInCommission] AS [IncludeVatInCommission], 
  [vAllocations].[ExchangeDate] AS [ExchangeDate], 
  [vAllocations].[ExchangeDateForCommission] AS [ExchangeDateForCommission], 
  [vAllocations].[ExchangeRate] AS [ExchangeRate], 
  [vAllocations].[CommissionExchangeRate] AS [CommissionExchangeRate], 
  [vAllocations].[AverageExchangeRate] AS [AverageExchangeRate], 
  [vAllocations].[StatusId] AS [StatusId], 
  [vAllocations].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
  [vAllocations].[Author] AS [Author], 
  [vAllocations].[DtCreated] AS [DtCreated]
  FROM [dbo].[vAllocations] AS [vAllocations]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[AuditGroupId] IN (9107)) AND ([Extent1].[AuditGroupId] IS NOT NULL)
```

Queries generated on LinqPAD test

```
 exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ContainerNo], [t1].[ATD] AS [PortATD], [t0].[ServiceDate] AS [ATA_KL], [t0].[RateWithoutVat], [t1].[DestinationCityId]
FROM [Invoicing_SPB].[dbo].[vAllocations] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Tariff].[vContainerEntity] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ContainerId]) = [t1].[ContainerId]
WHERE ([t1].[DestinationCityId] = @p0) AND ([t0].[AuditGroupId] = @p1)',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=14,@p1=9107
```

I've tried to loop and get count of result collection dependting on predicate

```
Invoicing_SPBEntities invContext = new Invoicing_SPBEntities();
        CommonCodesEntities ccContext = new CommonCodesEntities();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            var allocations = (from a in invContext.vAllocations
                               where a.AuditGroupId == 9107
                               select a).AsEnumerable();

            var q = from a in allocations
                    join c in ccContext.vContainerEntity on a.ContainerId equals c.ContainerId
                    select new
                    {
                        ContainerNo = a.ContainerNo,
                        PortATD = c.ATD,
                        ATA_KL = a.ServiceDate,
                        RateWithoutVat = a.RateWithoutVat,
                        OrderTypeId = c.OrderTypeId,
                        DestinationCityId = c.DestinationCityId,
                        Quantity = 1
                    };

            var result = q.ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Where(x=>x.DestinationCityId == 14).ToList().Count);
        }
```

**Resulting console output**

64
62
58
58
64
62
60
60
56
60
62
60
58
54
56
64
58

Very strange :D

Comment: Can you also post the generated SQL query?

Comment: Can you clarify what all those numbers are in the collection/view/result section of your question?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you pull all the data from vContainerEntity table and then do all the joins in memory. There might be some difference on how the entities are implemented in code, which might introduce difference. So try to rewrite your query so it runs on SQL directly.

Comment: I'm wondering why your join only gives **two** records in the result, because it should give **four** (based on your example). Because every record in the first table can be matched with every record in the second table (at least with your given data).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why, but your generated queries do not have any joins (except the one from linqpad). Just tried it out myself with two tables on SQL-Server and the classes autegenerated by the O/R designer. Seems to work as expected. Maybe there is some flaw in your data or class structure.

Comment: I tried to create console app with same query but it also fails, strange. But the same works perfect in LINQPad.